# How to Check whether the time is ending on the same day or the next day?

Tags: c#

My time is currently like the below format

| ShiftDate | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-04-2022 | 03:50 | 08:02 |
| 01-04-2022 | 08:02 | 09:02 |
| 01-04-2022 | 09:02 | 12:47 |
| 01-04-2022 | 13:00 | 17:12 |
| 01-04-2022 | 17:12 | 18:12 |
| 01-04-2022 | 18:12 | 01:12 |

I have two fields in my API request :

StartDayNumber and EndDayNumber

For Example : In my last record in the table, start time is 18:12 and end time 01:12,
so end time is ending on the second day. In this case my EndDayNumber value will increase by 1. Suppose StartDayNumber is 1 then EndaDaynumber should become 2.

I need to know how to calculate this endDayNumber by checking whether the end time is ending on the same day or the next day.

Currenlty my code looks like this :-

```
    int startDayNumber = 1;
    int endDayNumber = 1;
    
    DateTime sdt = DateTime.Parse(item.StartDatetime);
    DateTime edt = DateTime.Parse(item.EndDatetime);
    TimeSpan StartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sdt.ToString(), "h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
    TimeSpan EndTime = DateTime.ParseExact(edt.ToString(), "h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
    bool IsNextDay = EndTime < StartTime; //false
    
    //case 2
    TimeSpan StartTime2 = DateTime.ParseExact(sdt.ToString(), "h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
    TimeSpan EndTime2 = DateTime.ParseExact(edt.ToString(), "h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
    bool IsNextDay2 = EndTime2 < StartTime2; //true
    
    if (IsNextDay2 == true)
    {
    endDayNumber = startDayNumber + 1;
    }
```

The item.StartDateTime field is startTime in the table and
item.EndDateTime field is endTime in the table.

I am getting error String '2022-08-03 03:50:00' was not recognized as a valid DateTime,the time is not in correct format.
Please help me finding a solution to this.

Note : The time has no AM/PM and is in 24 hour format.

Comment: just after some weird -> DateTime -> string -> DateTime conversion

Comment: If you're on .NET 6, you can use the `TimeOnly` type.

Comment: If you assume that EndTime time is logically always after StartTime, that is the data is "valid" in this regard: then if EndTime < StartTime, it must be on a following day (because time progresses forward). Which day, that is the next day, or the day after, ... cannot not be determined by two time stamps and a start date alone.

Comment: The Data is Coming like this only @Christian.K. If you want the request format that i am using for the api call, Should i add that too?

Comment: Then EndDayNumber can only be 0 or 1 (or better yet, you can only say "IsSameDay = true|false". Because for all higher values of EndDayNumber you don't have enough data.

Comment: Default Values For StartDayNumber and EndDayNumber will Always be 1. @Christian.K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple helper class that you can use. It overrides the < and > operators, so you can use it to determine which time is greater. You would need to implement some error handling:

```cs
public class JustTime
{
    public int Hours {get;set;}
    public int Minutes {get;set;}
    
    public JustTime(string s)
    {
        string[] parts = s.Split(':');
        Hours = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
        Minutes = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);
    }
    
    public static bool operator < (JustTime l, JustTime r)
    {
        if (l.Hours < r.Hours)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (l.Hours == r.Hours)
        {
            return l.Minutes < r.Minutes;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public static bool operator > (JustTime l, JustTime r)
    {
        if (l.Hours > r.Hours)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (l.Hours == r.Hours)
        {
            return l.Minutes > r.Minutes;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```cs
int startDayNumber = 1;
int endDayNumber = 1;
    
var firstTime = new JustTime(item.StartDatetime);
var secondTime = new JustTime(item.EndDatetime);

if (firstTime > secondTime)
{
    endDayNumber = startDayNumber + 1;
}
```

If firstTime and secondTime are equal, you need to find out whether you consider it an empty interval or a full day.

Answer (score 3):

To check if a `DateTime` object is in a another day use this:

```
DateTime dateTimeStart = DateTime.ParseExact("01-04-2022 18:12", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dateTimeEnd = DateTime.ParseExact("02-04-2022 01:12", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime dateStartDay = dateTimeStart.Date;
DateTime dateEndDay = dateTimeEnd.Date;

TimeSpan timeSpanDifference = dateEndDay - dateStartDay;
Console.WriteLine(timeSpanDifference.TotalDays);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Db7c0

---

Assuming you have the following information

| ShiftDate | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-04-2022 | 18:12 | 01:12 |

Exactly as shown, as a string object you can do this, to get the correct `DateTime` objects.

Yes, I am assuming the format being `dd-MM-yyyy` if it is `MM-dd-yyyy` change it accordingly.

Though I am doubting the format, since you said you are getting this exception `I am getting error String '2022-08-03 03:50:00' was not recognized`, so based on the exception the format could be either `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-dd-MM`, again just need to change it to what ever format it actually is.

```
var shiftDateString = "01-04-2022";
var startTimeString = "18:12";
var endTimeString = "01:12";

var shiftDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(shiftDateString, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
shiftDateTime = shiftDateTime.Date;

var startDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(startTimeString, "HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var endDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(endTimeString, "HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

startDateTime = shiftDateTime.Add(startDateTime.TimeOfDay);
endDateTime = shiftDateTime.Add(endDateTime.TimeOfDay);

if (endDateTime < startDateTime)
    endDateTime = endDateTime.AddDays(1);

//output
Console.WriteLine(shiftDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"));
Console.WriteLine(startDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"));
Console.WriteLine(endDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"));

TimeSpan timeSpanDifference = endDateTime.Date - startDateTime.Date;
Console.WriteLine(timeSpanDifference.TotalDays);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/9VR4xE

Comment: ALthough this code is correct, it doesn't help @Saksham Srivastava, since he doesn't know the day of the second time.

Comment: This is also another way of doing it. Good answer. Thanks.